# How to add a key with fhc in FeedHenry?

Tags: ssh, redhat

When using feedhenry commandline interface, to add ssh key to Feedhenry,

```
fhc keys ssh add myKey <..mypath\Users\Blah\Desktop\pub>
```

I get the error below:

```
fhc ERR! Error adding Key: Invalid Key: no Base64 part to decode
```

Comment: The error looks like it's having trouble reading your key file. "<..mypath\Users\Blah\Desktop\pub>" is probably not a valid keyfile name on a unix system. Is your `fhc` line obscured? What is the actual command you're running and what are you actually giving as the key filename?

Comment: Yes i am using correct SSH key, I have answered the reason behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the platform, if there is space in the name field (not the username) in the Feedhenry studio, it didn't allow adding SSH key and issued strange message

Comment: do you recall what the full public key string was?
Here is a sample of the code that parses the uploaded public key.
https://gist.github.com/david-martin/6aaa5e3fac5f7505ef64d6ba18853203

 I wonder why it wasn't able to find the public key part, even if there was a space in the name?